# Linear programming, how to determine if tableau remain optimal with new cost function?

Tags: linear-programming

Some background: I have search on sensitivity analysis topic and even read some MIT papers on the topic. However, I cannot understand how to approach the solution, I feel I lack some basic idea. Can anyone help?
Given :
max : `x1 + 2 x2+ x3+ x4.`

```
s.t.: 2 x1 + x2 +5 x3 + x4 <=8  
2 x1 + 2 x2 +4 x4 <=12  
3 x1 +x2 +2 x3 <=18
```

the optimal tableau is
J  x1  x2 x3  x4  x5  x6   x7  b
1  1.2 0  0   2.8 0.2 0.9  0   12.4
0  1   1  0   2   0   1/2  0   6
0. 0.2 0. 1. -0.2 0.2 -0.1 0   0.4
0. 1.6 0  0  -1.6 -0.4 -0.3 1  11.2

a) Does the tableau remain optimal if the cost function now is: J = 3 x1+ 2 x2 +x3 +x4
b) Determine the range of c2 in the cost function within which the new cost function will remain optimal?

Comment: Where is this `c2` you're talking about?

Comment: it is the coefficient of x2